# Area of a region defined by boundaries

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Question: Find the area of the region whose boundary is defined by $\:y=\frac{1}{x},\:y=\:x^{\frac{2}{3}}, X-\text{axis},\:x=3$.

I am confused about which region to take for finding the area. Below are the possible regions that I am thinking about:

(1.) This graph takes the area of the following green-shaded region.

[image]

(2.) This graph takes the area of the following green-shaded region.

[image]

(3.) This graph takes the area of the following green-shaded region.

[image]

(4.) This graph takes the area of the following green and purple-shaded regions.

[image]

**Among the 4 graphs, which one should be the required area according to the question?
I think it should be (3.) (i.e. the third graph) since it is the region that is bounded by both the curves, the x-axis, and the line $x=3$. But is this the correct interpretation of the question? Could it be (1.) or (2.) or (3.)?**

Looking forward to hearing from you all.

Thank you!

Comment: The third graph is not bounded by the $x$-axis.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  So, if the question was, find the area of the region bounded by $y=\frac{1}{x},\:y=x^{\frac{2}{3}},\:X−axis,\:x=3$, then it would have been the third graph?
Also, which graph would you pick as the correct one for the question in the post? And why? Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: The second graph fits the requirements (although I would prefer the wording positive $x$-axis).  Notice that the second graph is bounded above by the curves $y = x^{2/3}$ and $y = 1/x$, bounded below by the $x$-axis, and bounded on the right by the line $x = 3$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Hmm, okay. I get the point. Would it be the same for the question: find the area of the region bounded by $y=\frac{1}{x},\:y=x^{\frac{2}{3}},\:X−axis,\:x=3$? Is this question slightly different from the one I have posted? Is this question concerned more with the area bounded by the two curves $y=\frac{1}{x},\:y=x^{\frac{2}{3}}$?  What is your thought on this?

Context: Using definite integration to find the area bounded by the curves, one of the axes (X or Y), and abscissas or ordinates.

Comment: Ohh I get it now, if the question mentions the area of the region bounded by 2 curves, abscissas, or ordinates, and the X-axis or Y-axis, then we have to take the area that is bounded by both curves, abscissas, or ordinates as well as the X-axis or Y. However, when the question simply asks to find the area of the region bounded by the 2 curves and abscissas or ordinates, then we don't need to consider the region that is bounded by the X-axis or Y-axis. I should have thought more carefully. I missed this basic concept to identify the region.

Thank you for your time and comment.